# Can't inject UserManager dependency in Abp controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, abp

I'm customizing `IdentityServer4` UI to use Angular, I created `SecurityController` with the constructor:

```
    public SecurityController(
        MyDbContext dbContext, 
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        AbpSignInManager signInManager
    )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

I'm getting the following exception when I refer to `localhost:[port]/Security/[any action]`:

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Acme.[ProjectName].Controllers.SecurityController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] userManager' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Acme.[ProjectName].EntityFrameworkCore.MyDbContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser], Volo.Abp.Identity.AspNetCore.AbpSignInManager)'.

P.S. If I remove `UserManager` dependency it works.

Any Idea?

EDIT:
Here's my `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplication<MyIdentityServerModule>();

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.InitializeApplication();

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/index.html");
    }
}
```

And here's `MyIdentityServerModule`:

```
    public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
    {
        var app = context.GetApplicationBuilder();
        var env = context.GetEnvironment();

        ...

        app.UseRouting();
        ...
        app.UseAuthentication();

        ...

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your `Startup.cs`, to show us how you register ASP.NET Core Identity?

Comment: @Métoule edited

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `IdentityServer`, but the `UserManager` class is part of the ASP.NET Identity middleware, and must be registered:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

You can check [the `IdentityServer` quickstart guide for ASP.NET Core](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/stable/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html#configure-identityserver) for more information.

Comment: Not woriing, I see the following error in the logs: `System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application`

Comment: It appears that the authentication part is already handled by ABP, and thus it's unnecessary to register the `UserManager` yourself. It seems that instead of using `UserManager`, ABP injects something called [`ICurrentUser`](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/CurrentUser), but that's way beyond my current knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove UseAuthentication() before UseIdentityServer(), because UseIdentityServer adds it for you.